# Calcular el Jitter en Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Quiero calcular el Jitter de la conexión en kotlin, partiendo de las latencias del ping a un servidor externo, buscando por internet me encontrado con el siguiente articulo [Que es el Jitter(en)](https://www.pingman.com/kb/article/what-is-jitter-57.html)

Traducido con Google trasnalte:

> **¿Cómo se calcula Jitter en PingPlotter Pro?** Para medir el Jitter, tomamos la diferencia entre las muestras, luego dividimos por el
>   número de muestras (menos 1). Aquí hay un ejemplo. Hemos recolectado 5
>   muestras con las siguientes latencias: 136, 184, 115, 148, 125 (en ese
>   orden). La latencia promedio es de 142 - (súmalos, divide por 5). El
>   'Jitter' se calcula tomando la diferencia entre las muestras. 136 a
>   184, dif = 48 184 a 115, dif = 69 115 a 148, diff = 33 148 a 125, diff
>   = 23 (Observe que solo tenemos 4 diferencias para 5 muestras). La diferencia total es 173, por lo que el jitter es 173/4 o 43.25.

Resumiendo los pasos

- Latencias = 136, 184, 115, 148, 125
- número de muestras = 5
- Suma de las diferencias n-(n-1) = 173
- Jitter 173 / 4 (número muestras menos 1)

Pues esos pasos con Kotlin para Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He creado la función `calcualteJitter`, se le debe pasar el array con los valores para obtener la fluctuación (jitter).
Si las muestras son 2 o menos siempre devuelve 0.0

```
fun calculateJitter(numArray: DoubleArray): Double {

    if (numArray.size < 2) return 0.0

    var sum: Double = 0.0
    for (i in numArray.indices) {
       if (i>0) sum += Math.abs(numArray[i-1] - numArray[i])
    }

    return sum.div(numArray.size-1)
}
```

**Su uso**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val numArray = doubleArrayOf(136.0, 184.0, 115.0, 148.0,125.0)

    val jitter = calculateJitter(numArray)

    System.out.format("Jitter = %.2f mms", jitter)
}
```

Se obtendrá `Jitter = 43.25 mms`